# HG ignore on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: mercurial, cloud9-ide

Where and how can I create/edit the .hgignore file within a Cloud9 IDE project?

The project was started by cloning a Mercurial repo. I don't see any mercurial specific files or directories.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Cloud9, but in Mercurial `.hgignore` always goes in the top level of your repository itself (not in `.hg`).  If they're supporting `.hgignore` at all, that's where they're doing it.